# Image in pdfkit not displaying?

Tags: node.js, node-pdfkit

I am using pdfkit to generate a pdf file in Node JS, but I am having trouble to display an image. The image is in the same folder as my Node javascript file, but it keeps telling me "no such file or directory".

I tried all the following:

```
doc.image('./Logo.png');
doc.image('/Logo.png');
doc.image('Logo.png');
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: check whether the file name is correct?

Comment: Yes, the file name is correct. I even copied and pasted it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `pdf.image('./img.png')` and it never worked. But when i tried `pdf.image('rootDirectory/Subfolder/img.png')`, it worked.

Hope this helps.